VS A2034 must be in segment block
I have encountered the problem shown in the screenshot below. As I am not very familiar with assembly code, I hope to receive guidance and help from everyone on how to solve the error in the screenshot.

I have tried the answers in this article, but the problem in the screenshot appears again, and I don't know how to solve it.

The code is as follows:
; https://gist.github.com/esoterix/df38008568c50d4f83123e3a90b62ebb

include ksamd64.inc

extern InstrumentationCallback:proc
EXTERNDEF __imp_RtlCaptureContext:QWORD

.code
InstrHook proc 

    mov  gs:[2e0h], rsp            ; Win10 TEB InstrumentationCallbackPreviousSp
    mov  gs:[2d8h], r10            ; Win10 TEB InstrumentationCallbackPreviousPc
    mov  r10, rcx                  ; Save original RCX
    sub  rsp, 4d0h                 ; Alloc stack space for CONTEXT structure
    and  rsp, -10h                 ; RSP must be 16 byte aligned before calls
    mov  rcx, rsp
    call __imp_RtlCaptureContext   ; Save the current register state. RtlCaptureContext does not require shadow space
    sub  rsp, 20h                  ; Shadow space
    call InstrumentationCallback   ; Call main instrumentation routine

InstrHook  endp

end


In the output I see that ml.exe is being executed to assemble things. ml.exe is a 32-bit MASM assembler. The 64-bit assembler is ml64.exe. The errors themselves also tell me  that your development environment is trying to build 32-bit code. The 64- bit registers aren't available in 32-bit code so you get errors about it.

How should I solve it? Thank you for your answer

If you need to change the project from 32 to 64bit. You can try this: Go Project > Properties > Configuration Manger and change your project to 64bit.
